# Erro ao tentar unir 3 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando unir trés tabelas do meu banco de dados, sendo elas `Propriedades | Licitacoes | Usuarios`. Só que toda hora da o mesmo erro! ele é:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in *** on line 61
```

O objetivo ao qual to tentando unir essa tabela é filtrar as informações na hora do `echo`, tanto que estou usando o `WHERE` no final do código. Quero que na hora que o usuário entrar na pagina em questão mostre apenas os resultados relacionado a ele, essa relação é dada pela `licitacoes` que o usuário possui e pelo `Nivel` que ele possui.

Já usei praticamente o mesmo código em outra ocasião e não deu nenhum erro parecido. Esse eu ja nao sei porque está dando! Podem me ajudar??

```
<?php
require_once "../conexao.php";
?>

<?php
$rs = $pdo->query(" SELECT a.ID as IDPROP, a.LICITI, a.NOME, a.NIVEL as NIPROP,
                           b.ID as IDLICI, b.ID_LICITI, b.ID_USER,
                           c.ID as IDCHAR, c.USUARIO, c.NIVEL as c.NICHAR 

                    FROM propriedades a INNER JOIN licitacoes b on (a.LICITI = b.ID_LICITI)
                                        INNER JOIN usuario c on (b.ID_USER = c.ID) 
                  ")->fetchAll();

if(!$rs){ print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); }foreach ($rs as $row){

?>

<?php echo $row['IDPROP'];?> = Informações da tabela propriedades
<?php echo $row['IDLICI'];?> = Informações da tabela licitacoes
<?php echo $row['IDCHAR'];?> = Informações da tabela usuario

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Tá faltando o `ON` no `INNER JOIN`, não? Tá aparecendo que erro?

Comment: Imprima a consulta e rode diretamente no banco veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: @Lucas realmente tava faltando o ON, porem isso não resolveu! O erro eu listei na pergunta! "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in *** on line 61"

Comment: @rray rodar diretamente no banco? Como assim?

Comment: Esse acontence pq `query()` falhou normalmente é erro na consulta, logo não consegue encadear o `fetchAll()`. Quando a consulta falha é retornado o sql state que diz a mensagem de erro, 'categoria' e código.

Comment: Qual o erro do SQL eu quis dizer, desculpe

Comment: Seria jogar a consulta em uma variável e imprimi-la, depois testar no workbench ou phpmyadmin, `$sql = 'select ....'; echo $sql; $pdo->query($sql); ...`

Comment: To achando que é algum mal fechamento! Porque a pagina nunca termina de carrega, é como se estivesse em loop infinito

Comment: Ainda tá aparecendo o `Fatal error`, depois que tu colocou o `ON`?

Comment: @Lucas ta sim. O erro ta o mesmo!

Comment: Vi outro erro aí: `c.NIVEL as c.NICHAR `, remove esse último *alias*, fica só `c.NIVEL as NICHAR`

Comment: @Lucas OBRIGADÃO. Esse ultimo erro que você falo solucionou o problema!

Comment: Show. Vou adicionar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei 2 erros no SQL: está faltando os `ON` nos `INNTER JOIN` e há um *alias* não necessário em `c.NIVEL as c.NICHAR`.

Segue o SQL correto:

```
SELECT a.ID as IDPROP, a.LICITI, a.NOME, a.NIVEL as NIPROP,
b.ID as IDLICI, b.ID_LICITI, b.ID_USER,
c.ID as IDCHAR, c.USUARIO, c.NIVEL as NICHAR 
FROM propriedades a
INNER JOIN licitacoes b ON (a.LICITI = b.ID_LICITI)
INNER JOIN usuario c ON (b.ID_USER = c.ID)
```

Como o SQL estava incorreto, a função `query()` retornava `false` e tentava chamar direto `fetchAll()`, mas como `false` não é um objeto, o PHP lança esse `Fatal error`.

Para contornar esse tipo de situação, é interessante armazenar a consulta em uma variável e testá-la, por exemplo:

```
$res = $pdo->query('...');
if ($res === false) {
    // erro na consulta
} else {
    $lista = $res->fetchAll();
}
```